# cognos report studio multiple columns average

Tags: business-intelligence, cognos

Im relatively new to cognos so please bear this in mind.

I wanted to create a report in report studio where i have 3 measures ( **A** ,**B** , **C** ) as columns and a 3rd calculated column as the average of these columns.

However , when using the average function , i cannot add multiple inputs .

i tried  the arithmetic alternative **( a+b+c)/3** because this will not handle cases when values are null

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can calculate a b c and put case when null then 0

Answer (score 0):

If nulls are not zero for average

```
case when 
    not (a is null and b is null and c is null)
then
    (coalesce(a,0) + coalesce(b,0) + coalesce(c,0)) /
    (case when a is not null then 1 else 0 end +
     case when b is not null then 1 else 0 end +
     case when c is not null then 1 else 0 end)
end
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion . However , in this case average will not be (/3) it will need to divide on the number of non null elements

Comment: I think this is one way to address the question. I came to a similar solution. If this isn't an answer to the question then the question needs to be edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a value count expression to count the non-null columns:

Value Count

```
CASE WHEN [A] is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0
+
CASE WHEN [B] is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0
+
CASE WHEN [C] is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0
```

Then you can use this new data item as the dividend for your average calculation:

Average

```
(coalesce([A],0) + coalesce([B],0) + coalesce([C],0))/[Value Count]
```

If division by 0 is a problem, you can wrap the average expression in another CASE to return null when [Value Count] is 0:

```
CASE 
WHEN [Value Count] > 0 THEN (coalesce([A],0) + coalesce([B],0) + coalesce([C],0))/[Value Count] 
ELSE null 
END
```